# How To Overlap The Taskbar On JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I am wondering if you could overlap the taskbar with a JFrame. If it is possible, how can I do it? My code makes the JFrame maximized, but still shows the taskbar. This is my code:

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
f.setUndecorated(true);
f.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but you'd end up with the frame been wrapped under the taskbar.

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
GraphicsConfiguration gc = gd.getDefaultConfiguration();
Rectangle bounds = gc.getBounds();

JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.setUndecorated(true);
f.setBounds(bounds);
f.setVisible(true);
```

Another choice might be to use [Full-Screen Exclusive Mode API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/index.html), based on the fact that you are making the frame undecoreated, this might be what you're after