# Can you create a seperate method for creating JFrame Sizes?

Tags: java, swing, methods, jframe

The previous question that I made was marked as a duplicate and the linked question was not anywhere close to what I need. I'm asking if it's possible to create a method that I can call to set the JFrame size.

So, I'm trying to make a JFrame GUI but I want to create the method outside of the GUI method, as in a GUISize method, and the JFrame works when the GUISize method isn't a method and the code is where the method is called.

This is for an assignment, but, none of it's technically marked. I'm just curious if it's possible to create a GUISize method for my Frame.

I've tried to reference the frame outside the method but can't, I've looked for ways to reference a JFrame outside of the method you build it in, but can't

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CQAC {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        GUI();
    }

    public static void GUI()
    {
        JFrame MainFrame = new JFrame("My First GUI");
        MainFrame.setTitle("CQAC");
        MainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        MainFrame.getContentPane().add(GUISize);
        GUISize();

        MainFrame.setVisible(true);

    }


    public static void GUISize()
    {
        Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension screenSize = kit.getScreenSize();
        int screenHeight = screenSize.height;
        int screenWidth = screenSize.width;
        GUI.MainFrame.setSize(screenWidth / 2, screenHeight / 2); 
        GUI.setLocation((screenWidth/4)-8,screenHeight/4);
    }

}
```

The code is supposed to open a blank JFrame that is half the size of the user's screen and placed in the middle of the screen, currently the JFrame doesn't open

Comment: The answer is "yes", the problem is, you're making using of `static` in places where it's not advisable and you're referencing an instance in you sizing method which has nothing to do with the one you created

Answer (score 1):

Your current code won't compile and I'm not going to all the reasons why.  `static` will make a fool of you quicker than just about anything else, learn to live without it, it has it's purposes and the way you're using really isn't one of them.

Instead.  Start by creating a new instance of the class and just its construction phase to build up the elements you need.  This way, you get out of the "can not reference non-static, blah, blah, blah" errors.

Instead, make a method whose sole job is to create the main frame, nothing else, have it return this instance.

Next, using the instance of the frame, pass that to your "make it sized" method and folia, you have a working pattern

For example...

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class CQAC {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Get out of the static context as soon as possible
        new CQAC();
    }

    public CQAC() {
        JFrame mainFrame = makeMainFrame();
        adaptToCurrentScreen(mainFrame);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    protected JFrame makeMainFrame() {
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("My First GUI");
        mainFrame.setTitle("CQAC");
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        return mainFrame;
    }

    protected void adaptToCurrentScreen(JFrame frame) {
        Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension screenSize = kit.getScreenSize();

        System.out.println(screenSize);
        int screenHeight = screenSize.height;
        int screenWidth = screenSize.width;
        frame.setSize(screenWidth / 2, screenHeight / 2);
        //frame.setLocation((screenWidth / 4) - 8, screenHeight / 4);
        // And because this is simpler :/
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

}
```

On a side note, `getScreenSize` this way you return the raw screen size, it won't take into consideration the size of things like the task bar or dock and menu bar on MacOS, which might make you window "look" offset when displayed.

Instead, you should be using the bounds of the `GraphicsConfiguration`, attached to the `GraphicsDevice` in the `GraphicsEnvironment` ... and no, these things can't be easy, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28619831/how-to-overlap-the-taskbar-on-jframe/28619854#28619854)

You might also want to taking a look at [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)